# How to set filter conditions as a cell reference in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, reference

I'm trying to use the filter function with a reference to a cell in another sheet as i have to copy the entire spreadsheet and be able to change the range of the filter.

I'm using cell and address together and hope it will return the text for use in the the formula. So far it look like this:

`=filter(Master!A2:E;CELLE(ADRESSE(Settings!B1))=Settings!B2)`

I keep getting an error displaying “FILTER has mismatched range sizes"

When I'm not using Celle function but writing Master!D2:D instead there is no error.

I have made a dummy spreadsheet so you can see what I mean.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KZhB1m0WzPlnGdzjJYZqQpsMsjoOpqQhlATmHs5dUm4/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space in Settings B1 and then try

```
=filter(Master!A2:E; indirect(Settings!B1)=Settings!B2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much.

Indirect was what I was looking for.
It seems to work like a charm!!

/ Jesper